# Textmate is garbling Rails test output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, colors, textmate, textmatebundles

Instead of colors I see this..

[Texmate Screenshot http://zeke.sikelianos.com/temp/textmate_tests_garbled.png](http://zeke.sikelianos.com/temp/textmate_tests_garbled.png)

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The shell that textmate is using to run your tests doesn't seem to be handling the shell text coloring correctly. "[32m" is the shell color code for green. It is surprising the red works, but green doesn't. You may want to try changing the shell that textmate is running tests in, or making sure that the shell it is using is properly using colors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using the redgreen gem. Disabling it solved the it for me.

Comment: I think you're right. Is there a way to disable gems temporarily on the fly? I was going to just uninstall it but other gems depend on it..

Comment: I just removed its require from `test_helper.rb` would that work for you?